# Restart thread once the threads inside it finished

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have thread `x` which I start like so:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
```

Inside `x` I have a `CyclicBarrier` with another 10 threads:

```
final CyclicBarrier _threadGate = new CyclicBarrier(10);
ArrayList<Thread> _threadList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I add the thread to the list

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
_threadList.add(new Thread() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
              _threadGate.await();
              //long processing code
```

So after the threads are ready I start them, it is important for them to start at the same time (well almost, looping takes time, even if its 0,01ms):

```
for (int i = 0; i < _threadList.size(); i++) {
   _threadList.get(i).start();
}
```

Now, the end of `x`, the main thread, is like this:

```
}, 0, repeatTimer, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If `repeatTimer` is `300` this means that it starts again the 10 threads after 5 minutes.

The time for the 10 threads to finish is an UNKNOWN amount, but it is under 5 minutes. Somewhere between 2 and 4 minutes for sure.

**What I want to achieve**

Once the 10 threads finish, restart X but with a delay of 5 seconds.
For this I have been thinking of setting the `repeatTimer` value to the time elapsed by the 10 threads + 5 seconds (I dont know how to do it, I dont know w hen last thread finishes its task), but is this correct? or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: You can not restart Java threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the necessity of having `SchedulingExecutorService` here. You can just wait until all threads finish their job using [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Here's a simple exapmple:

```
while (!stopped) {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(N);
    // create and start your threads
    latch.await(); // this method blocks until each Thread calls countDown()
    // wait here 5 seconds if you want
}
```

Decrement the latch in last action of each thread:

```
public void run() {
   _threadGate.await();
   // thread actions
   latch.countDown();
}
```

Comment: it has to be a thread because I have more threads and I'd like it to wait a few seconds before restarting, without using thread.Sleep to obstruct other threads

Comment: @Alpha2k nothing changes, you can still run provided code in a separate thread, so sleep will not affect other threads